# .Net switching control suits

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, syncfusion

I have developed a windows form project using Telerik controls. Now for some reason I've to switch to Syncfusion controls. What is the best way to switch to new controls? Do I have to drag and drop all the stuff again..?? Or is there a any other option which may be less time consuming.

Comment: I am not sure what the reason for the vendor switch is, but I would recommend contacting the Telerik support if you have not done so till now. I believe that the guys there will do their best to assist you and to save you the time and efforts to rework your application.

Answer (score 1):

It's very time consuming. It's not only a matter to change the controls. Probably they are totally different in terms of events, costants and worse in terms of functionality. You will need to test all of your code and probably rewrite the UI interaction methods.
If you really need to do that, take your time, and use a version control system to create a branch for the new version while maintaining support for the old version still using the Telerik controls

Comment: Branch is definitly the best way. Even if you could change all the syntax automatically. you don't know if the controls will have the behavior you expect them.

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the references in your `*.Designer.cs` files, but you'll probably run into errors when the Designer file attempts to assign properties that have existed in the Telerik controls and don't exist in the Syncfusion ones.

This approach will probably be less work than remaking every form, but it'll still take some time.